# How can I validate email and password fields, if both or one of the text fields are null?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[Can anyone help me how to put checks in this code. How can I validate this sign in function with a validation so that my application gives an error with the text fields are null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lvPc.png)

```
private void loginUser(final String email, final String password) {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        if(password.length() < 6)
                        {
                            Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(activity_main,"Password length must be over 6",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            snackBar.show();
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,DashBoard.class));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: It would help if you would provide a stack trace, but I'm guessing it's a NullPointerException because you don't check the password for null.

Comment: Can you tell me the easiest way to find if the email or password field is empty, regarding this code?

Comment: Using a debugger, or using a traceprint or log statement to print the value.  Or if you are asking how to get your application to cope with a missing field, **test** for `null`; e.g. `if (password == null) {...}`

Comment: Do not post image of code . add the code in question.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No error, but when I log in with empty text fields, the app crashes

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!email.equals("") && !password.equals("")){
    // this part will execute only when email and password are not null/empty.
    // and the app can continue to make an attempt for login.
    loginUser(email,password);
}else{
    // if here... it means email or password field is empty or not being
    // preserved correctly.
 // so you can:
    // 1. display msg here... for ex "pls fill all fields!"
    // 2. or handle in any way you like
}
```

Do this when login button is clicked.
hope this will resolve the problem. :)